# Add multiple values from TextFormField in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am looking for some help on adding different values from TextFormField, I am using a reusable widget to generate textformfields, I want to add the values that will be entered by the user and display them in one card. any help on the same would be appreciated.

**This is the TextFormField, which are being generated through reusable widgets from a separate class.**

`

```
TextFormField(
        onChanged: (value) {
          value = value;
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: labelText,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return '$labelText Should Not Be Empty';
          }
          return null;
        },
      ),`
```

This is how I am implementing ResuableTextFields,

```
ReusableTextField(
                  labelText: 'Work Date',
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime),
```

Comment: Please explain more, your question is not clear, what  is the problem?

Comment: I have textformfield, which will be taking user input values, I need to add them all and display the result.

Answer (score 0):

First define a form key at your state

```
class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
.
.
.
}
```

then assign your key to your Form

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
```

then create variables like _text and assign them to your textformfields like

```
onSaved: (String val) {
                _text= val;
              },
```

then on your form define a button and on click of that button save the form and then all your variables are assigned and you can use them

```
onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                }
              }
```